# trying to get rid of the NULL

Tags: sql, null, left-join

I have 2 tables which i am trying to join.

Table name: Students
Columns: Id , First_name

Table name: Papers
Columns: Title, Grade, Student_id

“Student_id” is a foreign key referencing “id” (“Id” should be a primary key, auto increment )

Then insert values into each table.
Run this insert after you have created the correct table:

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name) VALUES
('Caleb'), ('Samantha'), ('Raj'), ('Carlos'), ('Lisa');
INSERT INTO papers (student_id, title, grade ) VALUES
(1, 'My First Book Report', 60),
(1, 'My Second Book Report', 75),
(2, 'Russian Lit Through The Ages', 94),
(2, 'De Montaigne and The Art of The Essay', 98),
(4, 'Borges and Magical Realism', 89);
```

I did this

```
(select a.Id, a.first_name, b.title, b.grade
from students a left join papers b
on a.id = b.student_id);
```

and got this....

```
First name  Title   Grade
Caleb   My first book report    60
Caleb   My second book report   75
Samantha    Russian lit through the ages    94
Samantha    De Montaigne and the art of the essay   98
Raj NULL    NULL
Carlos  Borges and Magical Realism  89
Lisa    NULL    NULL
```

But i want to get this....

```
First name   Title                          Grade
Caleb         My first book report           60
Caleb         My second book report          75
Samantha      Russian lit through the ages   94
Samantha      De Montaigne and the art of the essay 98
Raj         MISSING                           0
Carlos        Borges and Magical Realism    89
Lisa          MISSING                            0
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `COALESCE()` function to replace the NULL/missing values with some placeholder, e.g.

```sql
SELECT a.Id,
       a.first_name,
       COALESCE(b.title, 'MISSING') AS title,
       COALESCE(b.grade, 0) AS grade
FROM students a
LEFT JOIN papers b ON a.id = b.student_id;
```